# MonoTouch error when compiling for the Device but not on Simulator: MONO_PATCH_INFO_JIT_ICALL_ADDR mono_marshal_safearray_create

Tags: ios, binding, crash, xamarin.ios, armv6

In MonoTouch I get this strange error when compiling for the device
(on the simulator it works fine, only when compiled for iPhone it
crashes):

```
    Loaded assembly:
    /private/var/mobile/Applications/FC6B7E68-E408-42A9-92A6-BC5AC73B3EEC/MyApp4.app/Mono.Security.dll
    [External]
    Loaded assembly:
    /private/var/mobile/Applications/FC6B7E68-E408-42A9-92A6-BC5AC73B3EEC/MyApp4.app/System.dll
    [External]
    Loaded assembly:
    /private/var/mobile/Applications/FC6B7E68-E408-42A9-92A6-BC5AC73B3EEC/MyApp4.app/monotouch.dll
    [External]
    unknown MONO_PATCH_INFO_JIT_ICALL_ADDR mono_marshal_safearray_create
    * Assertion: should not be reached at ../../../../../mono/mono/mini/mini.c:3179

    Stacktrace:

     at (wrapper managed-to-native)
    object.__icall_wrapper_mono_object_new_fast (intptr) <0xffffffff>

    Native stacktrace:

       0   MyApp4                     0x00628b38 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 456
       1   MyApp4                     0x006561e4 sigabrt_signal_handler + 168
       2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x337ed539 _sigtramp + 48
       3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x337e2f5b pthread_kill + 54
       4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x337dbfeb abort + 94
       5   MyApp4                     0x007a6310 monoeg_g_logv + 268
       6   MyApp4                     0x007a63e4 monoeg_assertion_message + 80
       7   MyApp4                     0x005fdea0 mono_resolve_patch_target + 2736
       8   MyApp4                     0x0061cd7c mono_aot_plt_resolve + 432
       9   MyApp4                     0x0062b460 mono_aot_plt_trampoline + 88
       10  MyApp4                     0x003948c0 generic_trampoline_aot_plt + 136
       11  MyApp4                     0x00357370
wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
+ 200
       12  MyApp4                     0x006013a8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 2892
       13  MyApp4                     0x00714dd8 mono_runtime_invoke + 200
       14  MyApp4                     0x0070d6cc mono_runtime_class_init_full + 2060
       15  MyApp4                     0x0070ceb0 mono_runtime_class_init + 28
       16  MyApp4                     0x005fed78 mono_jit_compile_method_inner + 224
       17  MyApp4                     0x005fffa4 mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt + 660
       18  MyApp4                     0x00600bcc mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 880
       19  MyApp4                     0x00714dd8 mono_runtime_invoke + 200
       20  MyApp4                     0x007cc154 monotouch_init + 640
       21  MyApp4                     0x005f71d8 main + 3704
       22  MyApp4                     0x00070b58 start + 52

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

This is driving me mad. I've no clue, the crash seems to happen before any code is called. I'm using two binding libraries (TestFlight and CorePlot) in my project, so maybe this is something related to the interop marshalling problems that MonoTouch has with the ARMV6 architecture of the iPhone.

Any help or suggestion, no matter how small, is appreciated.
Thanks!

UPDATE:
I can confirm that using the experimental compiler (setting in MonoDevelop: LLVM armv7 when compiling for the device) the app works fine, no crash at all. It seems really something related to the armv6 binding bug of MonoTouch. But I need to debug my App, and the LLVM compiler doesn't work in debug mode. Is there some workaround?

There is a discussion on the Xamarin mailing list right now:

http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Native-library-with-Monotouch-5-0-part-2-td3992408.html

Answer (score 0):

The runtime is looking for the method mono_marshal_safearray_create (inside the runtime), but that method isn't included in MonoTouch because it is related to COM (which isn't available on iOS).

This is just a guess, but do you have any attributes like this anywhere:

```
[MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.SafeArray, ...)]
```

in your code or any external libraries you're using? Have in mind that this is not the only way you can have code related to COM though.

In any case I recommend [filing a bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com), so that this issue can be fixed (or at least have better error reporting). Please include a way to reproduce it (either source code or the app itself should be fine for this bug).

Comment: No, I don't have any attribute like that. I'll try to submit a test case, thanks.